# Add int to Python dictionary existing key without overwriting said key

Tags: python

I would like to know if there was a way to work around where I am trying to add a user input 'int' to the same dictionary without overwriting the previous input instead adding on to it.

This is the main and blank dictionary

```
Packaged_goods={1:{'item':'Bread','price':1.45,'gst':0.10,'offer':'No'},

shopping_basket={}
```

the function where i select the item inside the mentioned dictionary

```
def package_select():
    sort=int(input('How do you want to sort your category by?\n'
                   '1.By name.\n'
                   '2.Ascending in price.\n'
                   '3.Descending in price.\n'
                   '4.Return previous menu\n'
                   'enter your input: '))
    if sort==1:
        res = sorted(Packaged_goods.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['item'])
        print(*res, sep = "\n")
        choose=(int(input('4.Exit back to menu\n'
                          'Enter your option(1-4): ')))
        # choose=int(input("Sorted by name: " + str(res)))
```

And here i would key in how many of that item i would want.

```
    if choose 1:
        qnty=int(input('How many do you want?: '))
        price=(Packaged_goods[choose]['price'])
        y = ((Packaged_goods[choose]['price']) * qnty)
        gst = (Packaged_goods[choose]['gst'])
        offer = (Packaged_goods[choose]['offer'])
        if choose==1:
            if 'Bread' not in shopping_basket.keys():
             shopping_basket['Bread'] ={'Quantity': qnty, 'Individual price': price, 'total': y, 'GST': gst, 'offer': offer}
            else:
                shopping_basket['Bread']['Quantity'].append(qnty)
```

Let's say I have keyed in 3 bread my output will be

```
Bread , {'Quantity': 3, 'Individual price': 1.45, 'total': 4.35, 'GST': 0.1, 'offer': 'No'}
```

Now I run the program again and I want to add 2 more bread, my desired out come would be

```
#desired outcome
    Bread , {'Quantity': 5, 'Individual price': 1.45, 'total': 4.35, 'GST': 0.1, 'offer': 'No'}
```

But instead it would give me the 'Quantity' value of the new int.

```
#actual outcome
    Bread , {'Quantity': 2, 'Individual price': 1.45, 'total': 4.35, 'GST': 0.1, 'offer': 'No'}
```

How may I go around this problem where it adds on to the value? Thank you

edit*
the code below when i run it

```
            if choose==1:
            if 'Bread' not in shopping_basket.keys():
             shopping_basket['Bread'] ={'Quantity': qnty, 'Individual price': price, 'total': y, 'GST': gst, 'offer': offer}
            else:
                shopping_basket['Bread']['Quantity'].append(qnty)
```

would give me an error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Hello. Your question is too complex to read. I suggest you to reduce it as much as possible to attract helpers.

Comment: Which (as narrowly defined as possible) part of your code is overwriting the quantity?

Comment: Consider this:-

Packaged_goods = {1: {'item': 'Bread', 'price': 1.45, 'gst': 0.10, 'offer': 'No'},
                  2: {'item': 'Cereal', 'price': 7.00, 'gst': 0.49, 'offer': 'Yes'},
                  3: {'item': 'Crackers', 'price': 3.10, 'gst': 0.22, 'offer': 'No'}}

Packaged_goods[1]['price'] += 0.54
print(Packaged_goods[1])

Comment: @ScottHunter, Thank you for your feedback, i have removed some part of the code not needed.

Comment: Your code should give you an error, as `append` isn't a member function `int`s have. However, I doubt you ever execute that branch anyway as you've said "I run the program again". Unless you're saving the dictionary somewhere on disk you are starting fresh every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you have used `append` for `int` values in the below piece of code:

```
shopping_basket['Bread']['Quantity'].append(qnty)
```

Instead you should use this:

```
shopping_basket['Bread']['Quantity'] += qnty
```

Comment: `append` will not change the value of an `int`, it will throw an exception. I don't believe that branch is being run at all.

Comment: Yes, if it was `list`, it would run fine but it surely causes error for integer

Comment: Yes, i would get an `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'` error, Above is just the steps i have tried

Comment: @yongjie is the problem solved now? Or is it still same?

Comment: @PrakashDahal Ah yes! Just tried it and it works flawlessly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Consider changing the following line:

```
shopping_basket['Bread']['Quantity'].append(qnty)
```

to

```
shopping_basket['Bread']['Quantity'] += qnty
```

In the former, you would just change the value to the new qnty. In the later, the quantity gets updated as required :)

Comment: `append` will not change the value of an `int`, it will throw an exception. I don't believe that branch is being run at all.

Comment: Yes, it would give me an error`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'`, above is just the steps I have tried